# When two different processes are accessing the same C shared memory, how can I synchronize around this global shared memory to avoid race conditions?

Tags: c, synchronization, ipc, shared-memory, race-condition

Below I have a writer and a reader, written in C. They use shared-memory (`shm_get` + `mmap`) to pass a message from writer to reader. Would someone be so kind as to show a newbie in C the best practice/example of how to synchronize around this global shared-memory? Basically when I'm reading from the shared memory, I don't want the writer to be writing anything, so that I don't end up with a race condition. This will be particularly important when I'm reading a 4-byte integer from the shared-memory. I don't want to run into the following situation:

- Reader reads 2 bytes, and proceeds to read the remaining 2 bytes for the 4-byte integer
- Writer comes along and overwrites the remaining 2 bytes
- Reader reads the wrong 2 bytes and calculates the wrong 4-byte integer

Below my C code for the writer and the reader! *How do I change it to synchronize around this global shared-memory?* I think I will need some kind of **shared-lock**.

Thanks a ton for your help!

**Writer:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STORAGE_ID "/SHM_TEST"
#define STORAGE_SIZE 32
#define DATA "Hello, World! From PID %d"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int res;
    int fd;
    int len;
    pid_t pid;
    void *addr;
    char data[STORAGE_SIZE];

    pid = getpid();
    sprintf(data, DATA, pid);

    // get shared memory file descriptor (NOT a file)
    fd = shm_open(STORAGE_ID, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 10;
    }

    // extend shared memory object as by default it's initialized with size 0
    res = ftruncate(fd, STORAGE_SIZE);
    if (res == -1)
    {
        perror("ftruncate");
        return 20;
    }

    // map shared memory to process address space
    addr = mmap(NULL, STORAGE_SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");
        return 30;
    }

    // place data into memory
    len = strlen(data) + 1;
    memcpy(addr, data, len);

    // wait for someone to read it
    sleep(2);

    // mmap cleanup
    res = munmap(addr, STORAGE_SIZE);
    if (res == -1)
    {
        perror("munmap");
        return 40;
    }

    // shm_open cleanup
    fd = shm_unlink(STORAGE_ID);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("unlink");
        return 100;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Reader:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STORAGE_ID "/SHM_TEST"
#define STORAGE_SIZE 32

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int res;
    int fd;
    char data[STORAGE_SIZE];
    pid_t pid;
    void *addr;

    pid = getpid();

    // get shared memory file descriptor (NOT a file)
    fd = shm_open(STORAGE_ID, O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 10;
    }

    // map shared memory to process address space
    addr = mmap(NULL, STORAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");
        return 30;
    }

    // place data into memory
    memcpy(data, addr, STORAGE_SIZE);

    printf("PID %d: Read from shared memory: \"%s\"\n", pid, data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See: [`sem_overview(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)